# Reason for belongs_to and has_many associations in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't get why need both these associations?

Surely if you define one, it would naturally imply the other. Therefore making one of them redundant.

Is there ever a situation where you would have one and not the other?

For example if I define:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

why do I then need to define:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Surely the above could be implied, and therefore use convention over configuration.

I'm just curious what the thinking was behind this! I'm sure there must be a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that straight forward.  For example if you have a belongs_to relation, the other end could represent a has_one or a has_many.

Secondly, sometimes you don't want the inverse association as it clogs up your model on the other end of the association. For example, you have a lot of classes referencing user but you don't need to know that a user has_many backorder_refirbished_car_parts

Answer (score 1):

First for this code it should be belongs_to if i understand right, as has_one will search at Post for comment_id and i don't think its the case for you and comment who has post_id defined on it

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has_one :post
  belongs_to :post 
 end
```

Second: if you don't want to define it, then You can do it but you will not be able to say:

```
 Comment.first.post
```

so if you don't need it don't write it.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head with - "if you don't need it don't write it". In other words "don't create redundant code" - which I completely agree with.

Answer (score 0):

Its not like `needed`. If you want only `belongs_to` or `has_many` association you could. There is not a dependency, If you followed convention of foreign key.

Comment: So could you think of a use-case where you would want to have one and not the other?

Comment: It depends what you want to define in model. If you want then add that association. no need to look at other associations.